# Reading an image from the clipboard with wxPython

Tags: python, image, memory, wxpython

How can I read an image from the clipboard? I'm able to read text from the clipboard using `wx.Clipboard`, but not images.

Is it possible to read images with `wx.Clipboard`? If not, is there another way?

I'm using Python 2.5 and Windows Vista 64-bit.

Comment: i have no idea why this question is closed !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me (tested on Mac OSX)

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'test frame',size=(790, 524))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnClick)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.clip = wx.Clipboard()
        self.x = wx.BitmapDataObject()
        self.bmp = None

    def OnClick(self, evt):
        self.clip.Open()
        self.clip.GetData(self.x)
        self.clip.Close()
        self.bmp = self.x.GetBitmap()
        self.Refresh()

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        if self.bmp:
            dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
            dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 20, 20, True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

To use this, I run it and when the frame comes up I copy an image using another program and then click in the wx frame, which then causes the copied image to be drawn within it.

Comment: +1, I use it for my app which works on both windows and OSX

Answer (score 0):

Python Imaging Library has an [ImageGrab](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagegrab.htm) module that can do just that. This works on windows only.