# How do I read a jpg or png from the windows clipboard in python and vice versa?

Tags: python, pywin32

I have an image (jpg, png, etc.) in the windows clipboard. I'd like to save it to a file.  win32clipboard would seem to be the answer, but every example I can find deals with text.

copy an image to the clipboard, then

```
import win32clipboard
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
with open(name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

fails with

```
TypeError: Specified clipboard format is not available
```

I'd also like to do the reverse - given an image file, write it to the clipboard.

Comment: If you're open to using the wx module you could do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629907/wx-read-image-from-clipboard

Comment: I'm trying to write a simple command line utility, and don't currently use wx, so I'd rather not go there.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I would just use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/):

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
im.save('somefile.png','PNG')
```

Comment: I was just looking at that, but I need both python 2.7 and 3.2 and PIL does not seem available for 3.2

Comment: @foosion: I think there's a precompiled binary for python 3.2 here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: This is dead simple for 2.7.  I was hoping that adding a few lines to the win32clipboard version would work like this.

Comment: works in 2.7. In 3.2 I get AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: @foosion: Change line 68 in ImageGrab.py to `if Image.isBytesType(data):` or use the updated installer.

Comment: Is there an opposite of ImageGrab - open an image file and copy the image to the clipboard?

Comment: Just wanted to mention: depending on how you've installed PIL, it might be just `import ImageGrab` instead of `from PIL import ImageGrab`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass a parameter to `GetClipboardData` specifying the format of the data you're looking for. You can use `EnumClipboardFormats` to see the formats that are available - when I copy something in Explorer there are 15 formats available to me.

**Edit 2:** Here's the code to get a filename after you've copied a file in Explorer. The answer will be completely different if you've copied an image from within a program, a browser for example.

```
import win32clipboard
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
filename_format = win32clipboard.RegisterClipboardFormat('FileName')
if win32clipboard.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(filename_format):
    input_filename = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(filename_format)
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

**Edit 3:** From the comments it's clear you have an actual image in the clipboard, not the filename of an image file. You've stated that you can't use PIL, so:

```
import win32clipboard
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
if win32clipboard.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(win32clipboard.CF_DIB):
    data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_DIB)
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

At this point you have a string (in Python 2) or bytes (in Python 3) that contains the image data. The only format you'll be able to save is .BMP, and you'll have to decode the [BITMAPINFOHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(v=VS.85).aspx) to get the parameters for a [BITMAPFILEHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(v=VS.85).aspx) that needs to be written to the front of the file.

Comment: I can create a filename myself.  Do I cycle through EnumClipboardFormats() starting with 0?  What do I do with the results?

Comment: @foosion, can you elaborate on exactly what's in the clipboard? Did you do a Copy on an image being displayed in a program, or on a filename in Explorer?

Comment: My current tests are to copy an image from a page in a web browser and from a paint program. Also, please see my comment to bgporter

Comment: Mark, I fear I may have been unclear. I'm not clicking on a filename in explorer, I'm clicking on an image and copying the image to the clipboard.

Comment: @foosion, your original question stated "I have an image file" which led to my confusion. Your comment above cleared it up.

Comment: The first code is giving me paths like "C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\ATTACH~1\FA1729~1.PNG" where the actual path is "C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\attachments\facetache (3)". How to retrieve actual paths using this?

Comment: @HamzaKhurshid you should be able to open the file with that name - it's a shortened version that Windows uses internally. If you really need to convert that filename into the long form, that would make a great new question.

Comment: I am not able to open using that filename. I have tried converting it to full path by listing all files of directory and choosing. I succeeded to a bit but failed in case of files with name starting from same characters.

Comment: Found the solution. Short path can be turned to long using win32api.GetLongPathName(shortPath)

Answer (score 5):

Using [PythonMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/) ([binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick)):

```
from PythonMagick import Image
Image("clipboard:").write("PNG32:clipboard.png")  # clipboard -> file
Image("clipboard.png").write("clipboard:")  # file -> clipboard
```

Comment: That looks promising and even supports both clip->file and file->clip.

Answer (score 4):

The function `win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()` has a parameter. The default parameter specifies that you want the contents of the clipboard as text. You need to pass in the value that specifies the data format you want the clipboard to give you.

The standard clipboard data formats are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649013%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_Standard_Clipboard_Formats).

**ALSO:**

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649038%28VS.85%29.aspx) for documentation on `EnumClipboardFormats()` -- basically, you need code like this *(untested)* to get the formats that are available currently on the clipboard:

```
formats = []
lastFormat = 0
while 1:
    nextFormat = win32clipboard.EnumClipboardFormats(lastFormat)
    if 0 == nextFormat:
         # all done -- get out of the loop
         break
    else:
         formats.append(nextFormat)
         lastFormat = nextFormat
# when you get here, formats contains a list of format codes that
# you can retrieve from the clipboard right now.
```

Comment: I just tried enumerating formats and got 49353, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0.  Do I just use 49353?  win32clipboard.OpenClipboard(49353) results in error: (1400, 'OpenClipboard', 'Invalid window handle.')

Comment: Did you see the page with documentation on what the format codes are? 8 is `BITMAPINFO` and 7 is `BITMAPV5HEADER`, both of which include the bitmap data. You may end up needing to learn more about how Windows handles images than you want to...

Comment: None of the codes listed in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729168(v=VS.85).aspx go as high as 49353.  Next value is 8, which is BITMAPINFO structure, but I'm not clear on what to do with it

Comment: 49353 isn't a standard format -- Win32 has a function `GetClipboardFormatName` that should give you a clue what that format contains.

Comment: @foosion, any format 49152 or greater isn't one of the hardcoded formats so it might vary from system to system. As bgporter says use `GetClipboardFormatName` to know what it is.

Comment: Re the first comment: The format code must be given as the parameter to `GetClipboardData()`, not to `OpenClipboard()`.