# Copy and paste an image from clipboard to Rmarkdown / .rmd code

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, clipboard

How can I copy an image to the clipboard and then directly insert/paste it in an .Rmd file?

See also here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4038

[image]

**Spoiler:** I wanted to post this question and then decided to give it a shot myself.
(It is a bit weird asking a question and answering it yourself, but when i read this i felt motivated enough :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

So far i got a workaround via python (see answer below), but it works and saved me quite some silly work. So i decided i might not be the only one googling that question and share my result.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a little RStudio addin and shared it here: https://github.com/Timag/imageclipr.
Edit: It works now without Python across plattforms (Mac, Windows, Linux), thanks to great contributions.

[image]

**Walkthrough:**

Basically i started here: [How do I read a jpg or png from the windows clipboard in python and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045264/how-do-i-read-a-jpg-or-png-from-the-windows-clipboard-in-python-and-vice-versa).

I use this code to save the image:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
im.save('somefile.png','PNG')
```

Then i wrote a wrapper with `library(reticulate)` to run the python code from R.
Thats what covers the "right part" of the gif: To copy the image to a directory.

For the "left part" I use `library(rstudioapi)`.
I take the current

- file: `getActiveDocumentContext()$id`
- line: `getActiveDocumentContext()$selection[[1]]$range$start`
- directory: `getActiveDocumentContext()$path`

And then wrote a small RStudio addin: https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/.

Comment: If you're willing to limit yourself to Windows, see `?readClipboard` for reading a bitmap from the clipboard in R.

Comment: hmm i tried it, but somehow it didnt work for me. Maybe i am missing sthg.

Comment: Tried what?  Please edit your question to show what you did that didn't work.