# Copy image from clipboard to markdown report

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, screenshot

I would like to be able to use a screen capture tool and copy the image directly in  a markdown report using rstudio.

One possible sequence of actions would be :

- use my windows snipping tool, or run a capture utility from R
- capture whatever needs to be captured
- save it in the working folder, or better in a folder set by options
- insert the `![](image.png)` code in the markdown

How can I do this or something similar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541381/4168169) self-answer using [imageclipr](https://github.com/Timag/imageclipr) may do the trick.