# how do i copy a file to clipboard in python?

Tags: python, file, clipboard

I want to copy a file named `"info.txt"` in the directory `"D:/documents"` to the clipboard but i don't want the end user to go through the hassle of copying it themselves. Instead, i want a python script to do it for them. How am I supposed to do that? Also, i don't want to copy the content of the file but the file itself. Is there a function in `pyperclip` that can do that or should i code something myself? I am also using windows 10 just in case the operating system matters.
as I said, i do not want to copy any string, all i want is to copy the file to my clipboard

Comment: If you want, you can check out for [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68164678/how-to-copy-cut-folder-from-one-folder-to-another-using-ctrlc-and-ctrlv)

Comment: @ti7, i do not mean to copy text but a file to the clipboard