# How to copy file from a folder to clipboard using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, clipboard

I have the path to a file, will usually be an image or a video, and I would like to copy this file to the clipboard so I can paste it somewhere else, eg: another folder, websites etc.

Disappointingly, the following doesn't work

```py
loc="C:/Path/To/File"
root.clipboard_clear()
root.clipboard_append(loc)
```

even though if I <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> the file and print `self.parent.clipboard_get()`, I get `loc`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try adding another line that says `root.clipboard_append(loc, type="FILE_NAME")`.  (You still want the existing append, to provide a plaintext version of the data in case the user pastes it into something that doesn't deal with files.)

Comment: @jasonharper I cant get it to work using that line, still works the same way as before, and if I remove ```root.clipboard_append(loc)```, the copy paste function stops working completely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70994384/18440600 Can I copy only the files inside the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think tkinter has method to copy files, but if you are on windows you can use the powershell command [`Set-Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?view=powershell-7.1). You can use `subprocess` module to run this command. Here is a minimal example.

```py
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk

def copy_file():
    #cmd = r"ls '{}' | Set-Clipboard".format(absolute_path) # if you only want the contents of folder to be copied
    cmd = r"gi '{}' | Set-Clipboard".format("background.png") # copies both folder and its contents
    subprocess.run(["powershell", "-command", cmd], shell=True)  # windows specific

root = tk.Tk()

copyfile = tk.Button(root, text="Copy file from c:\\", command=copy_file)
copyfile.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Now you might want to run the `copy_file` from another thread. Here is a reference to my old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68167062/15993687)

Comment: Works excellent for one file, thanks. What about pasting multiple files to the clipboard? I have a list of filepath strings, any way to pass it to Powershell so that when the user hits Ctrl+v all the files will be pasted?

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Art's answer, you can use this powershell command to copy multiple files or directories:

```
Get-Item -LiteralPath C:/Path/To/File1,C:/Path/To/File1,C:/Path/To/Dir1 | Set-Clipboard
```

So the python code will look like this:

```py
import subprocess

def copy_file(paths):
    cmd = r"Get-Item -LiteralPath {} | Set-Clipboard".format(','.join(paths))
    subprocess.run(["powershell", "-command", cmd], shell=True)
```

Please note that you may need to add `''` for each file/directory path.