# When a file is on the Windows clipboard, how can I (in Python) access its path?

Tags: python, clipboard

**I don't mean reading text from the clipboard.**

When a user right-clicks a file in Explorer and selects 'Copy', a value is placed on the clipboard that is not simply its path as a string. Pasting that value behaves differently in different contexts: in Explorer, it would create a new file; in Audacity, it copies the file contents into a new temp file; and in VS Code, it inserts the file's path. Copying a file's path to the clipboard doesn't have that same behavior. This value does not show up in Windows clipboard history because clipboard history seemingly tracks only strings.

The Python clipboard utilities I can find —- tkinter, Pyperclip, and win32clipboard -— do not register copies of this value at all when listening for new pastes, because they too are seemingly only listening for strings.

I want to listen for copies of this type of value and extract the path from them, the way VS Code does.

Is there a way I can do this in Python already? If not, can anyone recommend where I should start researching the clipboard API/syscalls?

Comment: The Windows clipboard has a type, and it only allows you to fetch if you ask for a compatible type.  When files get dropped, the type is CF_HDROP, not CF_TEXT.  When you use `win32clipboard.GetClipboardData` and specify CF_HDROP, it returns you a handle that you can pass to `DragQueryFile` to fetch the list of file names.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, the key is to decode the `CF_HDROP` clipboard format.  Here's some code I've been using for many years to do that and more.  It allows you to select and copy multiple files and will return a `list` containing the filenames.

```
import ctypes
import struct

from io import BytesIO

from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, HWND, HANDLE, HGLOBAL, UINT, LPVOID
from ctypes import c_size_t as SIZE_T

OpenClipboard = ctypes.windll.user32.OpenClipboard
OpenClipboard.argtypes = HWND,
OpenClipboard.restype = BOOL
EmptyClipboard = ctypes.windll.user32.EmptyClipboard
EmptyClipboard.restype = BOOL
GetClipboardData = ctypes.windll.user32.GetClipboardData
GetClipboardData.argtypes = UINT,
GetClipboardData.restype = HANDLE
SetClipboardData = ctypes.windll.user32.SetClipboardData
SetClipboardData.argtypes = UINT, HANDLE
SetClipboardData.restype = HANDLE
CloseClipboard = ctypes.windll.user32.CloseClipboard
CloseClipboard.restype = BOOL
IsClipboardFormatAvailable = ctypes.windll.user32.IsClipboardFormatAvailable
IsClipboardFormatAvailable.argtypes = UINT,
IsClipboardFormatAvailable.restype = BOOL
CF_UNICODETEXT = 13
CF_DIB = 8
CF_HDROP = 15

GlobalAlloc = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalAlloc
GlobalAlloc.argtypes = UINT, SIZE_T
GlobalAlloc.restype = HGLOBAL
GlobalLock = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalLock
GlobalLock.argtypes = HGLOBAL,
GlobalLock.restype = LPVOID
GlobalUnlock = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalUnlock
GlobalUnlock.argtypes = HGLOBAL,
GlobalSize = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalSize
GlobalSize.argtypes = HGLOBAL,
GlobalSize.restype = SIZE_T
GMEM_MOVEABLE = 0x0002
GMEM_ZEROINIT = 0x0040
GMEM_SHARE    = 0x2000
GHND = GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_ZEROINIT

unicode_type = type(u'')

def read_raw(fmt):
    handle = GetClipboardData(fmt)
    pcontents = GlobalLock(handle)
    size = GlobalSize(handle)
    raw_string = None
    if pcontents and size:
        raw_data = ctypes.create_string_buffer(size)
        ctypes.memmove(raw_data, pcontents, size)
        raw_string = raw_data.raw
    GlobalUnlock(handle)
    return raw_string
    
def get():
    text = None
    OpenClipboard(None)
    if IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_DIB):
        CloseClipboard()
        # from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7045677
        from PIL import ImageGrab
        return ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
    if IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_HDROP):
        raw_string = read_raw(CF_HDROP)
        CloseClipboard()
        pFiles, pt_x, pt_y, fNC, fWide = struct.unpack('IIIII', raw_string[:20])
        cooked = raw_string[pFiles:].decode('utf-16' if fWide else 'mbcs')
        return [name for name in cooked.split(u'\0') if name]
    handle = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT)
    pcontents = GlobalLock(handle)
    size = GlobalSize(handle)
    if pcontents and size:
        raw_data = ctypes.create_string_buffer(size)
        ctypes.memmove(raw_data, pcontents, size)
        text = raw_data.raw.decode('utf-16le').rstrip(u'\0')
    GlobalUnlock(handle)
    CloseClipboard()
    return text
```